# iOS passing property values to initialized views

Tags: ios, uiview, properties

I have a UIView subclass. The view has a float property. I initialize this subclass from another view (it's superView) like so:

```
    myView = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:aFrame];
```

The problem is, I am confused about how to assign values to myView's float property. When I try to assign a value just after initializing (from the superview's initWithFrame), nothing happens. Even when I try to to assign from another method or from the viewController it does not work.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your class is trying to use it in a method that is called before you set it. Make a custom initializer such as `-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andFloat:(float)f`. This will allow you to set the float when the object is created, so it will have that value upon instantiation. If this is not the issue, we will need to see more code!